# AJAX XML tree without server-side language

Tags: javascript, ajax, treeview

I need to make a nodes tree from data.xml file (as here [link text](http://www.mathertel.de/AJAXEngine/S03_AJAXControls/TreeView.aspx)) with AJAX.

Is it possible to do this without the server programming language?

I can get the whole data.xml file (all nodes) - but I need to load nodes dynamically (depending on the current tree view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any server side programming, you can only get the entire XML file (through an XmlHttpRequest) and work on it on the client side. If the file is not huge, this should not be a problem, though.

Once you have the file, there are ways of dealing with it and querying it for a specific node. How you do this specifically depends on various factors, but since your question provides no context in this regard, this is hard to tell.

Comment: I realized that i can do nodes sampling from xml file only with server-side language or I can get the whole xml file entirely and using js to make nodes sampling on the client-side.